# Bounding box of spherical sector (cone-sphere intersection)

Tags: geometry, algorithms, spheres

Given a spherical segment (its radius, direction and angle), how do I compute its axis-aligned bounding box in a easiest way?

Note that I'm interested in arbitrarily oriented segment, while the box must be axis-aligned. Tight oriented bounding box is trivial to compute.

The problem can be simplified to a bounding box of a spherical cap, but I couldn't find algorithm for that either.

[image: Spherical segment]